# Why are ?Images Compressed when Displayed on Android Phones/Emulator?

Tags: android, image, compression

Essentially I want an HD background on a layout, but instead of being a pristine image, it shows up extremely compressed.

Example:

Source Image:

[image]

Android Emulator version:

[image]

I thought maybe that it was just the emulator, but it looks that bad on the phone itself. I know these are high quality Samsung Galaxy S phones (these are the ones that came with *Avatar* preinstalled after all).

Does anyone know how to load images without compression? Source files are uncompressed pngs.

here's the code for what it's worth:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1"     android:background="@drawable/background" android:id="@+id/blank">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's compression and not just a smaller color space? Ex. the "good" image at least has an alpha channel, while the "bad" one does not.

Comment: I tried other file types to see if it was the png. Jpegs and Bitmaps give me the same result. It could be a smaller colorspace (i.e. 6 bit instead of 8), but then how do I change the colorspace to full color?

Comment: Okay, so it is converting to RGB565 from ARGB8888, but does anyone know how to stop this? I found sites that saw putting it in raw instead of drawable...no luck. I also tried adding an alpha channel and that didn't do anything either

Comment: If you haven't seen it already (you probably have) [this blog post](http://android.nakatome.net/2010/04/bitmap-basics.html) seems to shed more light on the issue.

Comment: Yeah, those were the two things I tried: putting it in raw and adding an alpha channel; neither worked...

Comment: NEVERMIND! It works, but not on the emulator: add an alpha channel and put it a a raw directory and I get full quality on the phone. :)

Comment: Great! You should answer your own question (and accept it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: The problem is the image is automatically converted into RGB565 colorspace from AGB888. To prevent this, make sure the image has an alpha channel and is in a "raw" directory instead of the "drawable" directory.

Answer (score 0):

The aapt may compress images when it builds the apk, but that compression is supposed to be lossless. The problem is probably somewhere else. Here are two possibilities.

If your image resource is being loaded from `res/drawable` on a device (or emulator) that is not mdpi, then it will be scaled as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence). One solution is to put the resource in the `res/drawable-nodpi` folder. Another is to provide several, density-specific images.

Another problem will arise if your background image does not match the size of the view. The view will automatically scale the image to fit the view size. You can prevent this by defining the background as an [XML Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap) with a `gravity` set to something that does not scale (such as `center`).